# how to place basic access authentication on my aws web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, http-authentication

I have a web app on AWS using CloudFront, an Elastic Load Balancer, and an EC2 host.

I am attempting to place ['Basic Access Authentication'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on it to give it simple password protection.

Do any of these AWS services provide this?

I notice that [S3 has documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader) on requiring the http authentication header, but I don't notice such documentation for the CloudFront, ELB, or EC2 services my app uses.

How can I setup Basic Access Authentication for my app?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. 
Just set up HTTP authentication on your webserver level.

You can follow this if You're using Nginx: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-basic-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

And for Apache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am able to do this running nginx directly on my local system. However, I am having trouble when running nginx from within a docker container, where the nginx.conf file does not have a 'location' section.